# Three of the Same JavaScript AJAX calls to same PHP page result in 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have tried `@session_start()` along with `session_write_close()`, but that's not working. The requests are the same. If the first 2 AJAX requests work, why not the 3rd? I've looked at `phpinfo()`, and I'm not exceeding any memory limits. Anything pointing me in the right direction is appreciated.

Comment: [Please read how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I'd recommend running curls from CLI to the endpoint to see what responses you get with different payloads and posting the response code.

Comment: show your code.

Comment: That's a lot of code. I would just like to know why this would occur. I have read other questions and nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was being hacked. Do to security reasons I'm unwilling to post my code that proved the hack and solved the issue. Thanks to all that tried to help. I did report to IC3.